# Desmarcar uma categoria x de todos os posts no wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Existe algum método para desmarcar uma categoria **"x"** de todos os posts no wordpress, sem precisar entrar em um post por vez e desmarcar a categoria?

Answer (score 3):

Conseguir desmarcar todos os posts que contém uma categoria "x" usando a seguinte query:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_term_relationships` WHERE `term_taxonomy_id` = id_categoria
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Mass set Categories](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mass-set-post-categories/)

Tem esse plugin que adiciona e remove categorias em massa.

Ele apresenta todos os posts de um só vez, você vai marcando e desmarcando as que desejar.

---

Existe também uma [idéia](http://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/deselect-categories-in-bulk-edit) para que algo parecido seja implementado no Wordpress.

Comment: esse plugin lista todos os posts, quero algo que desmarque todos os posts automaticamente que contenha categoria "sustentabilidade".

Comment: Não é mais fácil apagar a categoria então?

Comment: Não, porque ela serve para organizar as subcategorias, porém cadastraram errado, somente se marca a categoria filha, pois funciona com hierarquia, eu consegui usando query sql, vou postar como resposta caso alguém precise também.

Answer (score 1):

O mais lógico é que isso fosse feito com o *Bulk Edit* do WordPress, tal como comentado na [resposta do Ricardo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8890/desmarcar-uma-categoria-x-de-todos-os-posts-no-wordpress/8895#8895). Mas vi que o plugin *Mass Set Categories* é constituído de um único arquivo; porém o código me pareceu confuso e defasado, então fiz um *upgrade* rápido.

Basicamente, é uma interface mostrando todos os posts e com checkboxes listando as categorias. As funções principais são [`get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts), [`get_categories`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) e [`wp_set_post_categories`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_categories).

Adicionei uma opção no primeiro *post* que copia o valor do *checkbox* para todos os demais *posts* pra poder marcar/desmarcar em massa.

[image: plugin screenshot]

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOPT) Mass Set Categories
 * Plugin URI:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9006/201
 * Description: Baseado em http://wordpress.org/plugins/mass-set-post-categories/. Código revisado, simplificado e com nova funcionalidade de "Marcar/desmarcar todos".
 * Author:      brasofilo
 * License:     GPLv3
 */

add_action(
    'plugins_loaded',
    array ( B5F_Mass_Set_Categories::get_instance(), 'plugin_setup' )
);

class B5F_Mass_Set_Categories
{
    protected static $instance = NULL;
    public $plugin_url = '';
    public $plugin_path = '';

    /**
     * Acessar a instancia de trabalho deste plugin.
     *
     * @wp-hook plugins_loaded
     * @return  object of this class
     */
    public static function get_instance()
    {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Usado para iniciar os trabalhos normais do plugin.
     *
     * @wp-hook plugins_loaded
     * @return  void
     */
    public function plugin_setup()
    {
        $this->plugin_url    = plugins_url( '/', __FILE__ );
        $this->plugin_path   = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'set_plugin_page' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Constructor. Deixado publico e vazio intencionalmente.
     *
     * @see plugin_setup()
     */
    public function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Definir a página do plugin
     *
     * @wp-hook admin_menu
     */
    public function set_plugin_page () 
    {
        $hook = add_posts_page(
            'Mass Categories' ,  
            'Mass Categories',   
            'manage_options',  
            'mass-set-cats-t2',  
            array( $this, 'display_plugin_page' )
        );
        add_action( "admin_footer-$hook", array( $this, 'javascript' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Mostrar a página HTML do plugin
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function display_plugin_page() 
    {
        $args = array(
            'numberposts'     => -1,
            'offset'          => 0,
            'orderby'         => 'post_date',
            'order'           => 'DESC',
            'post_type'       => 'post',
            'post_status'     => 'publish' 
        ); 
        $posts = get_posts( $args );
        $boxes = $this->get_all_categories();
        ?> 
        <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Mass Set Categories</h2>
        Total posts: <?php echo count( $posts ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php $this->check_posted_data(); // imprime a mensagem de update abaixo do título ?>
        <div style="background-color:#FFF; border:#ccc 2px solid; padding:10px; width:95%"> 
        <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
         <input type="submit"  name="setcats" value="Submit" class="button-primary" >   <br />
        <?php
            wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'mass-set-cats-t2' );
            $print_str = '';
            $select_all = true;
            foreach ( $posts as $p )
            {
                $cats = get_the_category( $p->ID );
                $print_str .= '<h3><a href="' . get_edit_post_link($p->ID) . '">' . $p->post_title . "</a></h3>";
                foreach( $boxes as $id => $name )
                {
                    $check = $b1 = $b2 = $select_box = ''; // Reset aux vars
                    $filler = str_repeat( ' -', 30 - strlen(utf8_decode($id)) - strlen(utf8_decode($name)) ); // Recheio, considera caracteres acentuados
                    if( $select_all )
                    {
                        $select_box = sprintf(
                            '%1$s <a href="#" data-cat="[%2$s]" data-id="data-%3$s-%2$s" class="select-all">%4$s</a>',
                            $filler,
                            $id,
                            $p->ID,
                            __('Copy to all')
                        );
                    }
                    foreach( $cats as $c )
                    {
                        if( $c->term_id == $id )
                        {
                            $check = 'checked="checked"';
                            $b1 = '<b>';
                            $b2 = '</b>';
                        } 
                    }
                    $print_str .= sprintf( 
                        '<label><input type="checkbox" id="data-%1$s-%2$s" name="data[%1$s][%2$s]" %3$s>%4$s: %5$s</label>%6$s<br />',
                        $p->ID,
                        $id,
                        $check,
                        $b1 . $id,
                        $name . $b2,
                        $select_box
                    );
                }
                if( $select_all )
                    $select_all = false;
                $print_str .= '<hr />';
            }
            $print_str .= '</div>';
            echo $print_str; 
            ?>
         <input type="submit"  name="setcats" value="Submit" class="button-primary" >   
         </form>   
        <?php 
    }

    /**
     * Conferir nossos dados na global $_POST, usa nonce por segurança
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    private function check_posted_data()
    {
        if( !isset( $_POST['mass-set-cats-t2'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['mass-set-cats-t2'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
            return;

        if( isset( $_POST['setcats'] ) && $_POST['setcats'] == true )
        {
            foreach ( $_POST['data'] as $object_id => $cats )
            {
                 $ids = array_keys( $cats );
                 $ids = array_map( 'intval', $ids );
                 $ids = array_unique( $ids );
                 wp_set_post_categories( $object_id, $ids );
                 $ids = implode( ', ',$ids );
            }
            echo '<div style="width:99%; padding: 5px;" class="updated below-h2"><p>Updated</p></div>';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Recuperar todas as categorias e devolver IDs e Names
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function get_all_categories()
    {
        $args = array(
            'type'                     => 'post',
            'child_of'                 => 0,
            'parent'                   => '',
            'orderby'                  => 'id',
            'order'                    => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty'               => 0,
            'hierarchical'             => 1,
            'exclude'                  => '',
            'include'                  => '',
            'number'                   => '',
            'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
            'pad_counts'               => false );
        $categories = get_categories( $args ); 
        $boxes = array();
        foreach( $categories as $c )
        {
            $boxes[$c->term_id] = $c->name;
        }
        return $boxes;
    }

    /**
     * Imprimir JavaScript no footer da página do plugin
     *
     * @wp-hook admin_footer-$plugin_page
     * @return void
     */
    public function javascript()
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
            { 
                // Classe comum a todos os checkboxes
                $('.select-all').click( function()
                { 
                    // A category-id do elemento clicado
                    var data_cat = '[' + $(this).data('cat') + ']'; 
                    // Cada categoria comparte o mesmo data-id
                    var data_id = '#' + $(this).data('id'); 
                    $("input[name$='"+data_cat+"']").each( function() 
                    {
                        // Marcar todas as categorias igual que a clicada
                        $(this).prop( 'checked', $(data_id).prop('checked') ); 
                    });
                });
            });             
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
```