# Migração de conteúdo entre tipos de posts diferentes no Wordpress

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, plugin-wordpress

Bom dia,

Atualmente estou trabalhando com um projeto de um portal de notícias que é o agrupamento de 4 empresas diferentes, porém uma dessas empresas deixará de existir e todos os posts dela serão transferidos para outra empresa dentro do portal.

Para fazer a separação entre as empresas dentro do administrador eu estou utilizando o tipo de post padrão do WordPress(post) e mais 3 custom posts para as demais casas. A empresa que deixará de existir está utilizando o tipo de post padrão do WordPress.

A migração do conteúdo(post publicados) entre o tipo de post padrão e o custom post eu já realizei via query direta no banco e está ok.

No ententanto, o conteúdo permance com as categorias antigas e eu preciso fazer uma atualização com as categorias também.

Para exemplificar:

Suponha que eu tenho as seguintes categorias na empresa que será extinta:

- Empresa 1 (categoria pai)

  - Política (categoria filha)
  - Cidades (categoria filha)
  - Esporte (categoria filha)

E as seguintes categorias no custom post

- Empresa 2 (categoria pai)

  - Política (categoria filha)
  - Cidades (categoria filha)
  - Esporte (categoria filha)

Quando eu criei uma notícia no post padrão do WordPress eu atribui ao post as categorias Empresa 1 -> Política.

Após a mudança eu preciso alterar a referência que antes era Empresa 1 -> Política para Empresa 2 -> Política.

Para o custom post eu estou utilizando uma custom category específica devido as regras de negócio do projeto.

Para tentar entender como o WordPress trabalha quando eu seleciono uma categoria para um post eu fiquei observando o log de consultas do mysql, porém não consegui tirar muito proveito dessa abordagem, busquei plugins que pudessem me ajudar e os que eu encontrei faziam um "merge" entre categorias. Para referência os links dos plugins seguem abaixo:

[Batch-Move Posts wp plugin](https://wordp%C3%A5ress.org/plugins/batchmove/screenshots/)

[Term Management Tools](https://wordpress.org/plugins/term-management-tools/)

Essa migração de categorias é importante porque são as categorias que identificam de qual empresa é a notícia.

A única maneira que eu consegui ver de fazer essa atualziação é via query SQL direto no banco, porém as queries que executei não surtiram efeito.

Segue referência de duas das queries executadas:

```
UPDATE wp_relationships SET term_taxonomy_id = 270 WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 380;

UPDATE wp_term_relationships SET term_taxonomy_id = (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = 340) WHERE term_taxonomy_id = (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE term_id = 112747);
```

Comment: O problema exige mais tutano do que posso oferecer agora... confere se isso aqui ajuda: [Desmarcar uma categoria x de todos os posts no wordpress](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9006/201)

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, obrigado pelo comentário

Comment: Pode ser que a solução seja mesmo via MySQL, mas recomendo buscar por métodos nativos do WP... lá no [wordpress.se] tem muito material bom, é só pesquisar pelo nome da table field ou WP function/hook que vai encontrar referências legais

Answer (score -1):

Em uma pesquisa acabei encontrando sua questão.
Bom, vamos lá... Update neste post... (risos).
Portal de noticias é comigo mesmo. Já passei por isso...

Bom...
O que é mais pratico neste caso... (Em minha opinião)
É mudar o nome das categorias... 
E assim apos a mudança criar uma nova... Com um nome totalmente diferente para ter um referencial, afinal os nomes são semelhantes e acabamos confundindo.
Com a categoria diferente (Ex: XPO), vá direto em POSTS. 
Mudando assim todos os conteúdos da categoria (Politica 1) que pertence a Empresa 1. Em POSTS envie com facilidade para a categoria XPO, que acabou de criar.

Apos todos os posts na categoria nova. Mude o nome da Categoria e não esqueça o SLUG da categoria -> (URL)

Como vejo são muitos posts...

E você foi por um bom caminho que é o SQL, mas como tem nomes semelhantes pode confundir. E o próprio sistema poderá interpretar erradamente, Mas você esta se orientando por ID de taxonomia.

Neste caso o problema é a URL canônica, que possivelmente deve ficar como a antiga. Tenha cuidado. Por isso enfatizo. Na criação da NOVa CATEGORIA (ao qual vai importar), um nome diferente. A principio... 
Quando tudo já estiver lá... É só mudar...

Bom, sobre SEO e links...

Recomendo anotar as referencias anteriores de categorias. 
E usar o Plugin (Redirection), ele é muito bom. Neste caso citado iria apenas criar um única regra. E não todos os posts.

Eu particularmente não gosto de usar o SQL/Mysql. Somente em último caso.

Espero ter ajudado. 
Caso tenha alguma dúvida, favor comentar...

Abraço!

Comment: @Lucas Bernieri Ramos
Qual foi sua solução. Seu estudo de caso foi diferente?